# How to Extract Name,Phone Number and Email Address From Vision OCR result text in Android?

Tags: android, google-api, ocr, vision, image-scanner

Here is my sample code where i want to get details...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PHOTO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        launchMediaScanIntent();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeBitmapUri(this, imageUri);
            if (detector.isOperational() && bitmap != null) {
                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                SparseArray<TextBlock> textBlocks = detector.detect(frame);
                String blocks = "";
                String lines = "";
                String words = "";
                for (int index = 0; index < textBlocks.size(); index++) {
                    //extract scanned text blocks here
                    TextBlock tBlock = textBlocks.valueAt(index);
                    blocks = blocks + tBlock.getValue() + "\n" + "\n";
                    for (Text line : tBlock.getComponents()) {
                        //extract scanned text lines here
                        lines = lines + line.getValue() + "\n";

                        for (Text element : line.getComponents()) {
                            //extract scanned text words here
                            words = words + element.getValue() + ", ";
                        }
                    }
                }


                if (textBlocks.size() == 0) {
                    scanResults.setText("Scan Failed: Found nothing to scan");
                } else {
                    scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "Blocks: " + "\n");
                    scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + blocks + "\n");
                    scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "---------" + "\n");
                    scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "Lines: " + "\n");
                    scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + lines + "\n");
                    scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "---------" + "\n");
                    scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "Words: " + "\n");
                    scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + words + "\n");
                    scanResults.setText(scanResults.getText() + "---------" + "\n");
                }
            } else {
                scanResults.setText("Could not set up the detector!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: Have you got the solutions?.Please help me also to get it.

Answer (score 1):

You have nice libraries to parse link (emails,websites etc) like org.nibor.autolink
Concerning numbers you can have a look to libphonenumber. It is proposed by google and used by android. If you provide the country it can parse for you any format of the number.

Concerning names it is difficult. If you are using your app only for a country you can create a database with the names (in france we have a file in opendata proposed by a public servive) but it won't be complete...

Comment: @Geoffrey, will you please send me link of sdk or any libray for parsing  text.

Comment: Hello Rahul. I already put them. You have https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.nibor.autolink/autolink